# Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App with version (>= 3.1.0)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have .NET Core SDK 3.1.200 installed on my local machine.
I create a Asp.Net Core app (using Visual Studio) targeting `netcoreapp3.1`. I test it and it works fine.
But when I commit it to CI the build fails to get the nuget package:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App with version (>= 3.1.0)
  - Found 81 version(s) in MyGet [ Nearest version: 3.0.0-preview8-28405-07 ]
  - Found 73 version(s) in NuGet [ Nearest version: 2.2.8 ]
```

.NET Core 3.1 was released in December 2019 so why is the package not on nuget?
What am I missing?

**Update**

The CI is Azure Devops Pilelines and the agents are Windows machines that have Visual Studio 2017 installed. .Net core sdk 3.1 is not installed on the agents

Comment: What's your CI using? I suspect it should expect to find the package on the machine already, which would be fine if .NET Core SDK 3.1.x is installed on CI - but it won't work if your CI only has an old version of the SDK.

Comment: What is your CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**
Add the following task in your yaml

```yaml
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 3.1.x'
  inputs:
    version: 3.1.x
```

**Method 2:**

If using template editor, add `Use .Net Core` task and provide the version over there

**Note:** Make sure this should be the first task of the pipeline configured

Comment: Ok. That worked, but why was nuget trying to get that package? (I don't reference it directly in my proj) And why is the package not on nuget.org since .net core 3.1 is released?

Comment: Basically, you have built your application targeting 3.1.x but the sdk version in your pipeline is lower than that. While restoring the nuget packages, `Microsoft.NET.App` package will fail to restore as the sdk installed in pipeline does not support that version of it.

Comment: @LasangaGuruge How does one update the sdk on their pipeline? I'm having the same issue. My app is targeting a .NET Core 3.1 framework and am getting the error above. I'm using MS DevOps to pull my code from Github. Not sure if this matters but it's a solution that has several different projects in it. This most recent project that I added is the only .NET Core project. The others are Framework.